# External System's Documents Integrated to Salesforce

Tags: integration

I'm new to the developer side of Salesforce. Pardon my newbie-ness.

Is it possible for a document (ex. Word/Excel/PDF) that was either created or added to an external system, to be synced to a specific record in Salesforce? If so, what is the approach or tools I would need to explore and what is the potential level or effort?

Thank you!

Comment: The answer is yes, but you are going to need to dive way further into specifics before you'll get any solid help from the community.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to this

1)Using salesforce REST API you can trigger a call to SFDC to insert the record and the files will be linked to Attachment Object in SFDC .

2)You can also use SOAP to do this but REST API's are easier .In SOAP you can ask SFDC admin to get you the Enterprise WSDL or if you are building a product for multiple instance use Partner WSDL (This is loosely coupled)

3)You can use the new concept known as External Objects .For Pricing of this you may need to contact your SFDC AE .With external objects it will be just point and click configuration .Any external system exposing HTTP can be used as external objects with bit of apex code build .

If your external system can expose the data as the Odata then you dont need any apex code at SFDC end to convert into external objects .